# DOM quotes by depth to Delta quotes - anyone an idea?

Tags: dom

Ok, here we go. THis is a tricky one. FInancial market.

I have a trading application originally developped for the Rithmic API. FOr different reasons I am now moving real time data feed over to NxCore.

RIthmic has no concept of "DOM levels". I get moessages for every quote with volume, price. If a quote turns invalid, it gets 0 volume. WOrks nice....

NxCore does work with levels. I get a different message for every level (D1 - D10).

The problem is - I need to move from this to the RIthmic representation without sending too many errors / surplus messages.

Basically, the isue looks like this:

We establish a DOM - just ignore the items here. Interesting is D1 8 @ 11417

```
CBOT/YM.Z10 MM D2: 17 @ 11416 vs 10 @ 11421
CBOT/YM.Z10 MM D3: 10 @ 11415 vs 14 @ 11422
CBOT/YM.Z10 MM D5: 13 @ 11413 vs 13 @ 11424
CBOT/YM.Z10 MM D4: 17 @ 11414 vs 12 @ 11423
CBOT/YM.Z10 MM D9: 12 @ 11409 vs 12 @ 11428
CBOT/YM.Z10 MM D10: 14 @ 11408 vs 14 @ 11429
CBOT/YM.Z10 MM D5: 13 @ 11413 vs 16 @ 11424
CBOT/YM.Z10 MM D6: 20 @ 11412 vs 11 @ 11425
CBOT/YM.Z10 MM D1: 8 @ 11417 vs 3 @ 11420
CBOT/YM.Z10 2010-12-14 05:00:20.275000 BestBid 8 @ 11417

Something happens to he BestBid here..... so now it goes to 11418

CBOT/YM.Z10 MM D1: 3 @ 11418 vs 3 @ 11420
CBOT/YM.Z10 MM D2: 10 @ 11417 vs 10 @ 11421
CBOT/YM.Z10 MM D3: 17 @ 11416 vs 14 @ 11422
CBOT/YM.Z10 MM D4: 10 @ 11415 vs 12 @ 11423
CBOT/YM.Z10 MM D5: 16 @ 11414 vs 16 @ 11424
CBOT/YM.Z10 MM D6: 13 @ 11413 vs 11 @ 11425
CBOT/YM.Z10 MM D7: 17 @ 11412 vs 6 @ 11426
CBOT/YM.Z10 MM D8: 12 @ 11411 vs 5 @ 11427
CBOT/YM.Z10 MM D9: 18 @ 11410 vs 12 @ 11428
CBOT/YM.Z10 MM D10: 12 @ 11409 vs 14 @ 11429
CBOT/YM.Z10 2010-12-14 05:00:30.325000 BestBid 3 @ 11418

And that gives ups 10 updates just to move the DOM on the bid side. What I would need here is 2....
0 @ 11417
18 @ 11409
```

Every line is a separate callback into my code (or event if you want to use that term). I already know I need to keep some sort o fbuffer (D1 - D10 on both sides, bid and ask, with price, level and volume). My main problem are all the edge cases. When a volume changes, same DOM level, same price - easy.

But when the DOM moves like above, I get 10 updates but most need to be thrown away for me.

Anyone an idea? Also note that D1 - D10 do not necessarily handle the next 10 prices - sometimes (off hours) there are gaps.... which makes things REALLY nasty. I sort of know that if I get a D1 or D10 I can throw out all reported items "further down" the line. But my problem is mostly around gaps...

Oh, and it needs to be fast. Like 200.000 messages per second sometimes.

Anyone a smart idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have a DOM ladder for every symbol that you follow (two separate arrays, one for bid, one for ask).

This has to be dimensioned big enough for any kind of volatility that might be expected.
Usually 2000 levels will surely be enough for one day.
No problem with modern computer memories even if you follow quite a few symbols at the same time.

When a DOM event comes in just 
- update the volume at the appropriate price level 
- update the index of current inside bid or ask (if this information comes also with the event)

In other words ignore the "DOM level" information, just write the volume into the appropriate place.

It is safe to assume that there are no "holes" in the DOM, the levels are always positioned at one tick distance (this can be seen in your sample).

Hope I outlined this idea clear enough. If not feel free to ask.

Comment: Bad news is that I have to do the transaformation in a driver (no user interface) for archiving. 7xxx symbols at the same time now. More to come.

Answer (score 0):

If I compute this right:
2000 levels * 8000 symbols * 4 byte (size) * 2 (bid/ask) = 256 MB

No problem with todays computers.

Probably 2 bytes for size would also do the job which cuts it down to 128 MB.

(Btw if I get this right the job is to follow the complete US stocks universe via NxCore)

Comment: Acutally no. It only follows a small part of the CME group - which has more than 200k symbols in total. The options blog up the symbol count.